# Expression: "application to" or "application on"

Tags: prepositions, expressions, formal-language

I am trying to derive a title to my thesis and I am not a native English speaker.  So which one is the best form for expressing applications of methods:

"Probabilistic approaches in sensitivity analysis and inverse propagation of uncertainty, **application to mathematical** models in engineering"

or

"Probabilistic approaches in sensitivity analysis and inverse propagation of uncertainty, **application  on  mathematical** models in engineering"

Comment: `applicable to`?

Answer (score 1):

*Apply on* is a term used to mean place on the surface of, e.g. one *applies* a bandage *on* their skin.

*X applies to Y* means "X has to do with Y* in regard to relating topics.  So you want to use *to*.

*On X* can sometimes be used if X is a topic of a talk, conversation (e.g. "we are having a discussion on turtles") but this doesn't work with *apply* in a similar sense.